# How to implement headless browser for secure browser (HTTPS) or validate certificate by utilizing PhantomJs in Selenium?

Tags: selenium, browser, phantomjs, headless

I need to implement Headless Browser for HTTPS (validate certificate). For this I need to write extra line of code.

I have written for browser HTTP and it is working fine.

```
public class Headless {

  public static void main(String[] args)

 {

File src=new File("C:\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\bin\\phantomjs.exe");

  System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path",src.getAbsolutePath());

  WebDriver driver=new PhantomJSDriver();

  driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");

  System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

 }

}
```

I google it and get some info:-

```
phantomjs --ignore-ssl-errors=yes;
```

Comment: please format your code...

Comment: HI Vivek, and welcome to Stack Overflow.Could you describe in some more detail how far you've got i.e. what you've tried so far, and what about it isn't working? Remember you can [edit] your question to include more information.

Comment: Instead of "PhantomJS" I have used "HtmlUnitDriver" and unable to type to Username text box. WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
driver.get("https://XXXX.northamerica.abc.net:8443/#/login");
System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='ember-view ember")).sendKeys("XXXXXX"); Unable to type to Text box.Can any one check,Why is it not working for headless browser.I am able to execute it for Mozilla browser.

Comment: While Launching browser through "PhantunJS" driver then browser is not opening.I saw in screen shot.

Comment: While Launching browser through "PhantunJS" driver then browser is not opening.I saw in screen shot. But while launching via "HtmlUnitDriver()" then I am able to launch browser but unable to type in username text box.so over came this i tried to take screen shot but it is throwing the below error message.Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot

Comment: I have commented screen shot step  and able to proceed with HTMLUnit driver.......I got stuck in one page........Able to locate the element while executing script for "MozillaBrowser driver" but for same element unable to locate while executing script for "HTMLUnit driver"....it is throwing error message telling that unable to locate element........

Comment: if ( !driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@type='checkbox'])[1]")).isSelected() )
{
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@type='checkbox'])[1]")).click();
}
if ( !driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@type='checkbox'])[2]")).isSelected() )
{
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@type='checkbox'])[2]")).click();
}

Comment: It is recognizing first element but unable to recognize the second element.......It is working perfectly for "Mozilla browser driver" but it is throwing error message for "HtmlUnit driver".....Plz look into it

Answer (score 0):

```
DesiredCapabilities dcap = new DesiredCapabilities();
String[] phantomArgs = new String[] {
    "--ssl-protocol=any",
    "--ignore-ssl-errors=true"
};

dcap.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS, phantomArgs);

PhantomJSDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(dcap);
```

You can read more about the command-line options on this link: [Command Line Interface | PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/api/command-line.html)

Comment: Where do i need to include the above piece of code in the above program.

Comment: We need to use "WebDriver" as well.

Comment: PhantomJSDriver is an instance of WebDriver so you can use it.

Comment: Instead of "PhantomJS" I have used "HtmlUnitDriver" and unable to type to Username text box. WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(); driver.get("XXXX.northamerica.abc.net:8443/#/login"); System.out.println(driver.getTitle()); driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='ember-view ember")).sendKeys("XXXXXX"); Unable to type to Text box.Can any one check,Why is it not working for headless browser.I am able to execute it for Mozilla browser

Comment: While Launching browser through "PhantunJS" driver then browser is not opening.I saw in screen shot. – Vivek Aug 30 at 11:02   
     
While Launching browser through "PhantunJS" driver then browser is not opening.I saw in screen shot. But while launching via "HtmlUnitDriver()" then I am able to launch browser but unable to type in username text box.so over came this i tried to take screen shot but it is throwing the below error message.Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot

Comment: at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.findElementById(HtmlUnitDriver.java:998)
 at org.openqa.selenium.By$ById.findElement(By.java:218)
 at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver$5.call(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1705)
 at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver$5.call(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1701)
 at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.implicitlyWaitFor(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1347)
 at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.findElement(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1701)
 at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.findElement(HtmlUnitDriver.java:586)
 at